# getting undefined for value of child of table cell javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and have been trying to access value of a table cell using javascript. This field is a text field and I want to check if there is some text entered or not.
 My table looks like :

```
...
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>
<input .. value = "sometext"></input> </td>
<td>...</td>
...
```

my js code is something like:

```
func(){
var y = 


document.getElementById("someID").rows[9].cells[3].childNodes[0].value;
      alert("val of y"+y);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your childnode may be the space,new line or text but not the *input element*  and that is the reason you get undefined , because spaces don't have any property. So for accessing only elements and not spaces , you should use *children[0]* instead of *childnodes* .

Comment: This worked correctly using children[0]. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your td that wraps input.